# How to search for a specific key in firebase without having a reference to that key

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure looks like this:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRk1e.png)

My reference is initialized like this:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Butikker")
```

When i run this function in viewdidload, my console prints: nil nil

```
func fetchNearByPlaces() {
    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        print(dictionary["Longtitude"], dictionary["Latitude"])
    }
})
```

I want to print all the values that has the key: Longtitude and Latitude without referring to a specific path.

Comment: And if you print `dictionary`, what does it print?

Comment: nothing called dictionary["Longtitude"] check the syntax maybe they are in an array first

Comment: It prints the same as if i would print the snapshot of Apotek1 Røa.

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug!

Comment: I did debug it and it just won't print the value of Latitude and Longtitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When observing a node in Firebase by .childAdded, it returns each node, one at a time and the snapshot children can be accessed directly.

When observing by .value however, the snapshot contains the parent nodes and all of the children. In that case, to get at each child node, iterate over the snapshot like this:

```
let databaseRef = self.ref.child("Butikker")

databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        print(dictionary["Longitude"], dictionary["Latitude"])
    }
})
```

also, in Firebase 4, instead of FIRDataEventType.value, just use .value

Comment: Thank you, this did actually work. You just made my day